# Which of these is a better php function?

Tags: php, arrays, function

Given below are two PHP functions which basically does the same thing, What i want to know is which one of these is the best to use?

$lang is an array which stores other values

```
$lang = array(

    'default' => 'This is the default text',

    'site' => array(
        'name' => 'Website',
        'url' => 'website.com',
    ),

    'logo' => 'images/logo',

);
```

and please note that i will be using one of these function throughout the application for displaying text as the application i am building support multiple languages.

Function 1:

```
function lang($text='default') {

    global $lang;

    $text = explode(',',$text);

    if(!empty($text[1])) {
        $newtext = $lang[$text[0]][$text[1]];
    }
    else {
        $newtext = $lang[$text[0]]; 
    }

    echo $newtext;

}
```

Usage : `<?php lang('default'); ?> or <?php lang('site,name'); ?>`

Function 2:

```
function lang($text='default', $text2='') {

    global $lang;

    if(!empty($text2)) {
        $newtext = $lang[$text][$text2];
    }
    else {
        $newtext = $lang[$text]; 
    }

    echo $newtext;

}
```

Usage : `<?php lang('default'); ?> or <?php lang('site','name'); ?>`

Comment: both seems good to me, thats the reason i am asking you guys :D or you guys can go ahead and suggest a new function...

Comment: Then pick one (at random if you can't decide) and use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second, but I would rather split it into two methods.

Ex:

```
GetLanguage($site)
   returns an associative array of strings
```

And

```
GetLanguageKeyValue($site, $key)
    returns value as string
```

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, second function is more logical by the arguments.
And explode function in first one is slower than operations with arrays in second.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer function 2:  it is far more obvious that there are two parameters.

Comment: So true. No 1 reminds me of the term ["stringly typed"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2444303#2444303)...